# Adding text to the end of each line in Word

Tags: vba, text, ms-office, ms-word

I am trying to remove the current style from bullets lists and adding text to both the beginning and the end of each line. So far, the *InsertBefore* works, but to use the *"InsertAfter"*, I need to move the insert point to the left for one-letter space, otherwise the new text will be added to the beginning of the next line (to the right of the current line break mark).

```
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
With seletion
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
            oPara.Range.Select
            oPara.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
            oPara.Range.InsertBefore " * "
            oPara2.Range = .Range(oPara.Range.Start, oPara.Range.End - 1)
            oPara2.Range.InsertAfter "&&&"
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim rng As Range
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs 'or Selection.Paragraphs
     Set rng = oPara.Range
     With rng
        If .ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
           .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
           .InsertBefore " * "
           .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
           .Move wdCharacter, -1
           .InsertAfter "&&&"
        End If
     End With
 Next
```

Comment: * 1&&&
 * 1&&&
 * 1&&&
 * 1&&&
 * 1&&&
 * &&&1
it works except for the last one

Comment: I forgot to mention that.  I thought you could maybe figure that part out.